# Possible moth identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

There's a flying insect being caught indoors today in Sydney Australia. Before it is being caught, it basically flies like a moth. However googling of *Tinea pellionella* and other cloth moths does not suggest it is a cloth moth as hair is missing from its very small sized head.

It is also known to be very common every year when spring approaches in australia

To assist identification, the bug was caught in a plastic jar to allow multiple angles of it to be photographed

[image]

- Measured body length (not including long antennae): 1.1 cm
- Color: Brown an golden brown with lustre
- Legs: 6 (front pair very short, middle pair is forked, hind legs have some golden brown feathery structure)
- Head is black, very small and have no hair

[image]

- Here one can easily see the hindlegs are covered by some bristle like golden brown feathery structures, and also its shiny golden segmented abdomen

[image]

- The camera is not fast enough to capture it unblur when it is flying, but the few moments when it opened its wings can be seen here extracted from a video

[image]

And these are our best shots using the iphone camera in capturing its flight with its wings fully opened.

> Is this a type of moth, is it a pest or is it neutral. What is the species?

Comment: It is a moth, so belongs to the order of Lepidoptera, and to the unoffical suborder of microlepidoptera. These are notoriously difficult, even with good literature, which i'm not sure exists for Australia (European myself).

Comment: Do you find [this](http://www.ozanimals.com/Insect/Tobacco-Moth/Ephestia/elutella.html) similar?

Comment: That might be it, as the glossiness of the wings, the feathery ends and the colors patterns matches. Strangely, I don't seemed to see any of the two dark horizontal bands that is present in all other google images of the species (except mine and the photo shown in your link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a Bogong Moth,the migration point was really helpful !!**
They migrate in masses around the
 1. Victorian alps
 2. southern Australia (Sydney,Canberra)
 3. New Zealand..
**Agrotis infusa**,
*These are pests which affect many plants,they're not neutral and they
Cause some attentive damage*

[**More on this and the site which helped me**](https://australianmuseum.net.au/bogong-moth)